# Firefox sometimes reporting insecure items on page with https

Tags: firefox, security, https

I have just installed a self-signed cert for usage on a test server and I added an exception in Firefox to trust it.

When I load the page normally it shows the lock and all is fine; however if I click on a link on the page and go to another page and THEN click back; the page loads but it now has the "warning" icon, which obviously means that not all elements on the page are loaded via a secure connection.

Why is this caused by going back to the page and not when loading it normally? ...is there anyway you can see a list of the elements it *thinks* aren't secure? I really couldn't find any.

Comment: Use firebug extension and look under NET tab

Comment: Also, try setting browser.sessionhistory.max_total_viewers to 0 in abount:config https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/985416

Comment: @JohnKiller Tried the NET panel in FB but everything was loading over port 443; couldn't see anything that was loading over the standard 80 or 8080.

Comment: @JohnKiller Checked out that thread, error doesn't really bother me, just concerned it might happen on the live site to, so didn't want it happening to users; but I guess it can't be helped if it's a FF issue. :(

Comment: If you try changing the firefox option and the issue vanish then yes, it's a firefox bug